# gitlab ci have manual jobs and automatic jobs in the same yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have several jobs in my gitlab ci
the dependency goes as follows

```
prebuild_job1 -> buildjob1,buildjob2,buildjob3 -> deployjob1

prebuild_job2 -> buildjob2 -> deployjob2
```

prebuild_job1 is manual - person has to trigger it
prebuild_job2 should happen on merge request

so when i create a merge request, the prebuild_job2 and buildjob2 run, but deployjob2 fails to start because it depends on a different project

the trigger is a merge request.

It is defined as follows :

```
prebuild_job2:
  stage: pre_build
  only:
    - merge_requests
  environment:
    name: tag
  tags:
    - tag
  script:
   - ./build.sh
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

buildjob2:
  stage: build
  only:
    - merge_requests
  needs: ["prebuild_job2"]
  environment:
    name: tag
  tags:
    - tag
  before_script:
    - ./before_build.sh
  script:
    - ./build2.sh


  e2e-tests:
  stage: test
  when: on_success
  only:
    - merge_requests
  needs: ["buildjob2"]
  allow_failure: true
  variables:
    SUITE_TYPE: "test"
    BUILD_NUMBER: ${BUILD_NUMBER}
    SLACK: "slack_channel_id"
  trigger:
    project: path/to/project
    branch: master
    strategy: depend
```

it fails to start with this message:
[image]

How do i fix it?

Comment: Can you add more details on how each of the gitlab ci of the two projects looks like as it is not very clear where all these jobs are and how they are related.

Comment: @Raghu i added the entire script

Comment: can you also add the gitlab-ci.yml for the downstream project to your question as the error message refers to "rules" in the downstream project which are preventing the pipeline trigger.